# Deep Diff Test Failures in Karma with Mocha

Tags: mocha.js, karma-runner, chai

I am running the following test:

```
describe("objects", function () {
    it("should equal", function () {
        var a = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: {
                a: 1,
                b: 2,
                c: {
                    a: 1,
                    b: 2,
                    x: 3
                }
            }
        };

        var b = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: {
                a: 1,
                b: 2,
                c: {
                    a: 1,
                    b: 2,
                    x: 4
                }
            }
        };
        a.should.deep.equal(b);
    });
});
```

The test fails as expected, but the error message is not at all helpful.

`AssertionError: expected { Object (a, b, ...) } to deeply equal { Object (a, b, ...) }`

How would I get it so that it outputs a prettified json comparison instead?

Libraries I am currently using:

- karma 0.12.1
- karma-mocha 0.1.6
- karma-mocha-reporter 0.3.0
- karma-chai 0.1.0

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a solution for this

Comment: I'll have to use Jasmine again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change where the message gets truncated with the following:

`chai.config.truncateThreshold = 0`

So for your example:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

chai.config.truncateThreshold = 0;

describe.only("objects", function () {
    it("should equal", function () {
        var a = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: {
                a: 1,
                b: 2,
                c: {
                    a: 1,
                    b: 2,
                    x: 3
                }
            }
        };

        var b = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: {
                a: 1,
                b: 2,
                c: {
                    a: 1,
                    b: 2,
                    x: 4
                }
            }
        };
        expect(a).to.deep.equal(b);
    });
});
```

Which will result in:

```
AssertionError: expected { a: 1, b: 2, c: { a: 1, b: 2, c: { a: 1, b: 2, x: 3 } } } to deeply equal { a: 1, b: 2, c: { a: 1, b: 2, c: { a: 1, b: 2, x: 4 } } }
+ expected - actual

     "b": 2
     "c": {
       "a": 1
       "b": 2
+      "x": 4
-      "x": 3
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: btw, even when there is no truncation (e.g. `[ Array(2) ] to deeply equal [ Array(2) ]`), `chai.config.truncateThreshold = 0` will help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The mocha reporter has an option for this: `showDiff: true`

You can stick this in your karma config:

```
config.set({
    frameworks: [ 'mocha', 'chai', ... ],
    plugins: [
        require('karma-mocha'),
        require('karma-chai'),
        require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
        ...
    ],
    reporters: [ 'mocha', ... ],
    mochaReporter: {
        showDiff: true, // <-- This!
    },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use assert-diff library to show only the difference when test fails.

```
var assert = require('assert-diff');

describe("objects", function () {
    it("should equal", function () {
        var a = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: {
                a: 1,
                b: 2,
                c: {
                    a: 1,
                    b: 2,
                    x: 3
                }
            }
        };

        var b = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: {
                a: 1,
                b: 2,
                c: {
                    a: 1,
                    b: 2,
                    x: 4
                }
            }
        };
        assert.deepEqual(a, b);
    });
});
```

this will give you an error with the difference

```
  1) objects should equal:
     AssertionError: { a: 1, b: 2, c: { a: 1, b: 2, c: { a: 1, b: 2, x: 3 } } } deepEqual { a: 1, b: 2, c: { a: 1, b: 2, c: { a: 1, b: 2, x: 4 } } }
 {
   c: {
     c: {
-      x: 4
+      x: 3
     }
   }
 }
```